# В комплексном экране не работают оповещения zabbix 3.0

Tags: zabbix, мониторинг

На вкладке "Комплексные экраны" не работают звуковые глобальные оповещения (которые в отдельном окошке появляются), хотя графики обновляются каждую секунду, на других страницах все нормально. Оповещение появляется тогда, когда полностью перегрузишь страницу.

Если у кого-нибудь есть zabbix 3.0, посмотрите у себя, если открыть комплексный экран, выставить интервал обновления для user 1 секунду, будут ли у Вас глобальные оповещения работать, пока не перегрузишь страницу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле class.cmessages.js изменил значение в строчке updateFrequency на 1, эта строчка отвечает за частоту проверки оповещений.